# How to prevent pandas.Dataframe.to_latex from adding escape \ characters before latex formula characters (i.e dollar signs/brackets)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

I'm trying to produce a data table for a paper that I can insert into the LaTeX document, using pandas. However, the entries of both the table headers and the elements need to be mathematical formulas in latex (`$...$`). In my case, this is because some of them because they have subscripts, and others because all the table values need to have upper and lower error bars, i.e like `0.21^{+0.03}_{-0.05}` etc...

So I made a pandas table with string elements such as `'$0.21^{+0.03}_{-0.05}$'`. The dollar signs are there because LaTeX needs to interpret this as a formula as far as I can tell. Unfortunately, when I then try to write the table into latex format with `df.to_latex(...)`, the parser puts escape characters `\` in front of every dollar sign. The same seems to happen with the underscores, brackets, and all the latex formula characters (`'$0.21^{+0.03}_{-0.05}$'` becomes `'\$0.21\^\{+0.03\}\_\{-0.05\}$'`

How would I be able to block this from happening?

Comment: Based on the [`DataFrame.to_latex` help](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html), you can supply `escape = False` (default is `True`). Try it.

Comment: Ah right, yes it works, I must have misunderstood it when I looked. Thanks. Do you want to answer the question so I can mark it or should I close this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [`DataFrame.to_latex` help](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html), you can supply `escape = False` (default is `True`).

```
DataFrame.to_latex(escape = False, ...)
```