# How to remove extra backslashes from the output of pandas.to_latex?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I am using the pandas `to_latex` function to export a pandas dataframe to a text that can be pasted into a LaTeX  file.

Here is a dataframe example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Country': ['Burma', 'Burundi'], 'Capital': ['Naypyidaw','Gitega']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I am using `to_latex` with `index=False` in order not to export the row names:

```
df.to_latex(index=False)
```

This yields the following chunk of text:

```
\\begin{tabular}{ll}\n\\toprule\n   
Capital &  Country \\\\\n\\midrule\n 
Naypyidaw &    Burma \\\\\n    
Gitega &  Burundi \\\\\n
\\bottomrule\n
\\end{tabular}\n
```

Is there a parameter that I could tweak to get rid of these backslashes and extra `\n`?

This is my desired output:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Capital &  Country \\ 
Naypyidaw &    Burma \\    
Gitega &  Burundi 
\end{tabular}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`df.to_latex(index=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) returns a `string`. If you want the "*treated*" value of it, use the `print` function

```
print(df.to_latex(index=False))
```

Then use the output.

Comment: Wow! I think this is the first time I receive a viable answer less than a minute after posting my question. Thanks a lot, Rafael!

Comment: @Sheldon glad to help !

Comment: It helps, but does not remove escape characters in other cases, like `\$` for example.

Comment: OK, found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516653/how-to-prevent-pandas-dataframe-to-latex-from-adding-escape-characters-before/48551350